# Android ViewBadger not showing

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to use a badge in android by exploiting https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger

To this end I am inflating a TextView like

```
        TextView target = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.menu_item_badge);
        BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(this.getContext(), target);
        badge.setText("1");
        int droidGreen = Color.parseColor("#A4C639");
        badge.setBadgeBackgroundColor(droidGreen);
        badge.show();
```

The problem is I can't see the badge

Comment: try this instead BadgeView badge = new BadgeView(this, target);

Comment: I am inside an Adapter

Comment: Try to set some text to Target textview.